# BX-6Q1 ledboard text SDK

Tags: sdk, led

I have a LED board Models "BX-6Q1", I can change the text via software, but I need Code to control the text by some SDK file

```
 https://en.onbonbx.com/upload/download/Specifications%20of%20BX-6Q1.pdf
```

I have gone through the above document. On this, they have given ". We offer you C#, java, SDK, VB, C++; We
also offer you the completed SDK port and technological service." , But I can't find it anywhere

Where do i get the SDK File

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally, I found the SDK in below URL

http://5js361.com/download/SDK/YQ6QSDK/index.html